# Postgresql Query - Ordering by result of subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery

I have a query where I want to select all users who like a given set of artists. There also are some other WHERE criteria on country etc. Here's what the schema looks like.

```
          users                     favourite_artists             artists

+----------+------------+    +-----------+------------+    +--------+--------+
|    id    |  country   |    |  user_id  |  artist_id |    |  id    |  name  |
+----------+------------+    +-----------+------------+    +--------+--------+
|     1    |     gb     |    |     1     |      6     |    |   1    |  Muse  |
|     2    |     gb     |    |     1     |      5     |    |   2    |  RATM  |
|     3    |     us     |    |     1     |      3     |    |   3    |  ABBA  | 
|     4    |     us     |    |     2     |      3     |    |   4    |   U2   |
+----------+------------+    +-----------+------------+    +--------+--------+
```

I want to order them by the number of those artists they like. I also want to include users who don't like any of the artists but who match the WHERE criteria. The expected result set would look like.

```
+--------+---------------+----------------+
|   id   |    country    |   match_count  |
+--------+---------------+----------------+
|    6   |      gb       |       4        |
|    9   |      gb       |       4        |
|    2   |      gb       |       3        |
|    1   |      gb       |       2        |
|    5   |      gb       |       0        |
|    4   |      gb       |       0        |
+--------+---------------+----------------+
```

I've been trying to do it using a subquery to get the match_count and ordering by that but it's performing pretty slowly so I thought there'd have to be a better way.

```
   SELECT users.id, users.country
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM favourite_artists 
    WHERE user_id = users.id AND artist_id IN (1,3,4,9)) AS match_count        
   FROM "users" 
   WHERE users.country = 'gb'
   ORDER BY match_count DESC;
```

I'm using Postgresql 9.0.7. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your query is executing one subquery for every row in `users`. Such queries are called "*correlated subqueries*" and their performance, quite understandably, sucks.

Instead you want a join:

```
SELECT users.id, users.country, count(artist_id) as match_count
FROM users
LEFT JOIN favourite_artists ON user_id = users.id AND artist_id IN (1,3,4,9)
WHERE users.country = 'gb'
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

This query will get the joining rows far more efficiently, assuming you have an index on `favourite_artists(user_id)` - or better yet a [multi-column index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) `favourite_artists(user_id, artist_id)`.

Comment: Relying on the position in the ORDER BY clause violates relational theory, which holds that the order of fields in the result set is not determined.  I suggest "ORDER BY match_count" instead.

Comment: My panties are not in a bunch.  I simply consider it poor practice to **ever** rely on numeric positional indicators when 1) it is just as easy and more clear to specify the field name and 2) the ordering of the fields, while supported by the SQL language, violates the relational model.  It's not a big-enough deal to start a war over.  I simply offered it as a useful suggestion.